# What assemblies do need to add/change to deploy silverlight web application to Windows Azure [Error]?

Tags: c#, silverlight, deployment, azure, assemblies

I have a silverlight based application consisting of charts using silverlight toolkit and connected to database using RIA Services (Domain Service class, ADO.NET entity model). I want to deploy it to my windows azure account online.

I recently encountered

> Instance 1 of role Website is busy
>   Instance 1 of role Website is cycling

I encountered this issue again and again.

Note : My Windows Azure SDK is updated and I already deployed a MVC based application.

This SOF answer guides that i should add these assemblies : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8966859/1319922

But these are for MVC based project and mine is Silverlight based (using C#).

**Is there any assemblies left which i need to add ?** Also my project works fine in Local Host.

*Also do i need to set some assemblies `CopyLocal = true` ? And if YES which ones ?*

*Why i am not able to deploy my app (and getting above error), Is there any other issue ?*

Please Reply
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using RIA Services it's possible that these assemblies are not available on your Web Role. To view all assemblies available on Web Roles, follow this link: http://gacviewer.cloudapp.net/

You should double check with the assemblies in your ASP.NET Web Role (the one hosting the RIA Services application), and change all assemblies that you cant find on the gacviewer website to **CopyLocal = true**

Besides that, if you activate Remote Desktop on your Web Role, you can (for testing purposes) connect through RDP and take a look at the event viewer to see what assemblies are missing.

Comment: gacviewer seems quite nice for that task.
To add to your dependency hint/answer: Please also ensure that no transitive dependencies are missing.
E.g. you have your ASP.NET project __A__ has a dependency on a custom library project __B__. __B__ then depends on some library __X__ in your GAC. Running locally will work fine but unless you add a reference from __A__ to __X__ (with CopyLocal) your deployment will also fail to run.

Comment: Thanks It helped...I was missing some RIA Services reference.

Comment: but hey...my app is showing "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied." when i try to access it using the URL provided.. Why ?