# Azure could not find Reference to EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, entity-framework-4.3

My ASP.NET MVC 4 app is running perfectly on IIS and in IEExpress Environment.
Unfortunately it seems to have a problem with different Versions of EntityFramework.
All references are double and tripple checked for occurences of EF 4.1.0.0. All is unsing EF 4.3.0.0 right now.
Somewhere the system seems to have a reference to 4.1.0.0 and its trying to find it. With no success.

All related external libs are marked as "copy local=true"

```
    Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Critical: 201 : Role entrypoint could not be created:
System.TypeLoadException: Unable to load the role entry point due to the following exceptions:
-- System.IO.FileLoadException: Die Datei oder Assembly "EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0,      Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden.     Die gefundene Manifestdefinition der Assembly stimmt nicht mit dem Assemblyverweis überein. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Dateiname: "EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"

=== Zustandsinformationen vor Bindung ===
LOG: Benutzer = COREI7\markus
LOG: DisplayName = EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/Dev/TFS/BettrFit/BettrFit.Azure/csx/Debug/roles/BettrFit/approot/bin
LOG: Ursprünglicher PrivatePath =   D:\Dev\TFS\BettrFit\BettrFit.Azure\csx\Debug\roles\BettrFit\approot\bin
Aufruf von Assembly : System.Web.Http.Data.EntityFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: Diese Bindung startet im default-Load-Kontext.
LOG: Es wurde keine Anwendungskonfigurationsdatei gefunden.
LOG: Die Hostkonfigurationsdatei wird verwendet: 
LOG: Die Computerkonfigurationsdatei von C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 \config\machine.config wird verwendet.
LOG: Verweis nach der Richtlinie: EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
LOG: Download von neuem URL   file:///D:/Dev/TFS/BettrFit/BettrFit.Azure/csx/Debug/roles/BettrFit/approot/bin/EntityFramework.DLL.
WRN: Der Vergleich des Assemblynamens führte zum Konflikt: Nebenversion.
ERR: Das Setup der Assembly konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden (hr = 0x80131040). Die Suche wurde beendet.

 ---> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Mindestens ein Typ in der Assembly kann  nicht geladen werden. Rufen Sie die LoaderExceptions-Eigenschaft ab, wenn Sie weitere Informationen  benötigen.
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   bei System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   bei Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetRoleEntryPoint(Assembly    entryPointAssembly)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetRoleEntryPoint(Assembly  entryPointAssembly)
   bei Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.CreateRoleEntryPoint(RoleType roleTypeEnum)
   bei Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRoleInternal(RoleType    roleTypeEnum)
Das Programm "[2372] WaIISHost.exe: Verwaltet (v4.0.30319)" wurde mit Code -1 (0xffffffff) beendet.
```

Hope you guys could give some hints on how to fix this problem.

I investigated the Data.EntityFramework assembly:

```
Assembly a = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("System.Web.Http.Data.EntityFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");

foreach (AssemblyName i in a.GetReferencedAssemblies())
{
     Trace.TraceInformation("Ref Assemblies:" + i.Name+" "+i.Version);
}
```

**It shows that its depending upon EntityFramework 4.1.0.0 as the default.**
How could I change that?
The Web.Config seems to be not used at loading time - here I tried the rebinding already.

Comment: Have you also checked for indirect references which may be locally installed (in your global assembly cache) and missing in Azure? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10142356/468244 + comments.

Comment: I checked with GACViewer - so far no luck. I suspect that System.Web.Http.Entityframework might causing the problem. 
But I have no clue how to check to which version that lib is referencing too.
In the log it is named as Calling Assembly. How could I configure it to use the "newer" version as it is deployed with the package?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it via supplying an app.config file with my Web-Role Project.
It seems that the Azure Startup-Code is using an App.Config file instead of the usually used Web.Config.

My app.config adds the runtime/assemplyreferences redirect binding code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use assembly redirection to redirect 4.1.0.0 to 4.3.0.0:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0 - 4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: Sorry. my web.config contained altready such a redirect. Tried yours too - no luck. 
It seems that the system is ignoring the web.config runtime section.