# Azure deployment is cycling for a long time

Tags: deployment, azure

```
12:08:41 - Preparing deployment for Windows Azure MSDN - Visual Studio Ultimate with     
Subscription ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
12:08:41 - Connecting...
12:08:41 - Verifying storage account 'cck'...
12:08:43 - Uploading Package...
12:41:00 - Creating...
12:57:14 - Created Deployment ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
12:57:14 - Starting...
12:57:55 - Initializing...
12:57:55 - Instance 0 of role RIS2048.ConsultaClick.Web is in an unknown state
12:59:03 - Instance 0 of role RIS2048.ConsultaClick.Web is starting the virtual machine
13:00:40 - Instance 0 of role RIS2048.ConsultaClick.Web is in an unknown state
13:01:48 - Instance 0 of role RIS2048.ConsultaClick.Web is busy
13:06:12 - Instance 0 of role RIS2048.ConsultaClick.Web is cycling
```

It's now 13:31, more than 1 hour stared ago and at 25 minutes the instance is cycling (I don't know what that means). Will it finish? When?

Here's part of my ServiceDefinition.csdef file with 2 VirtualApplications:

```
<Site name="Web">
    <VirtualApplication name="CCKPt"
                      physicalDirectory=".">
      <VirtualDirectory name="images"
                        physicalDirectory="..\RIS2048.ConsultaClick.WWWPacientes\imgpt" />
    </VirtualApplication>
    <VirtualApplication name="CCKRo"
                      physicalDirectory=".">
      <VirtualDirectory name="images"
                        physicalDirectory="..\RIS2048.ConsultaClick.WWWPacientes\imgro" />
    </VirtualApplication>
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Azure publish issues - Busy - Restarting - Busy - Cycling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966798/azure-publish-issues-busy-restarting-busy-cycling)

Comment: I have the same problem when I have 2 websites.

With only 1 website the deploy runs sucessfully.

Help!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is this a new app you just built? And does it run locally in the emulator? First thing I always check is the connection string for diagnostics, along with the session state provider. By default, your diagnostics are written to the emulator storage (meaning SQL Express on your local machine), and  SQL Express is used for session state, which doesn't exist in Windows Azure. Rather, you'd need to switch it to Cache or SQL Azure.

Comment: It is no't running on the emulator. And it's an application that has been sucessfully deployed once. The only difference now is that instead of one VirtualApplication I configured 2 VirtualApplications in the file ServiceDefinition.csdef

Comment: See the editing of the post with part of my ServiceDefinition.csdef file

Answer (score 0):

Likely means there's a problem.  Sometimes, if you're lucky, you can squeeze a little more info about where exactly it's bombing from IntelliTrace:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/06/07/using-intellitrace-to-debug-windows-azure-cloud-services.aspx