# Publishing MVC3 webapp to Azure: Busy - Cycling

Tags: deployment, azure

I have a MVC3 web application consisting Bing Translate API. Everything works fine on the emulator, but when I deploy it to Windows Azure, I encounter this issue again and again ( I retry more than twice):

```
Instance 0 of role Website is busy
Instance 0 of role Website is cycling
```

It stops at cycling for very long.
And in portal, I see this message:

`Waiting for role to start... System is initializing`

I already selected the "`Add deployable assemblies`", and check true all the reference `Copy Local = true`
I also checked connection string to my Account Storage, I set my project to work on cloud through an Account Storage.

And here my web.config for Bing Translate API

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_LanguageService" closeTimeout="00:25:00"
          openTimeout="00:25:00" receiveTimeout="00:25:00" sendTimeout="00:25:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/soap.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_LanguageService"
        contract="BingTranslator.LanguageService" name="BasicHttpBinding_LanguageService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I have searched for a long time but nothing works for me. Please give me your help.
Best Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Azure publish issues - Busy - Restarting - Busy - Cycling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966798/azure-publish-issues-busy-restarting-busy-cycling)

Comment: I have seen it, but not works for me! :(

Answer (score 0):

I can hit your something about how to translate these error to some information:

**Case One:** You status is looping within the Web Role:

1. WebRole Starting
2. WebRole Busy
3. WebRole Cycling
4. WebRole Unknown State
5. WebRole Restarting

This is potentially a role specific problem and Your best bet is to RDP to your instances and look for several things i.e. Azure Diagnostics Log for potential exception, Event Logs,  Azure BootStrapper Logs, IIS Configurator Logs, etc. This will help you to find the problem faster then any other method, unless you can get Azure Diagnostics logs from Azure Storage having all the details about your potential problem.

**Case Two:** Your status is looping within the Full Machine:

1. Starting...
2. Initializing...
3. WebRole Starting
4. WebRole Busy
5. WebRole Cycling
6. WebRole Restarting

This could be a machine specific problem where the VM itself is cycling, this is good candidate to contact Windows Azure Support team to investigate for you.

Comment: At last, I found my mistake is that the name of Account key is wrong and I forgot to set the default setting connection string to Azure Storage.

Thanks for all you attention!